# Maquetar resultados cURL para Dashboard

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, curl

Tengo varias páginas PHP que muestran distintas informaciones mediante el método post.

Quiero realizar un dashboard o una única página en la que llame mediante cURL a las distintas páginas PHP que reciben las variables por método post. (En este caso estas variables las voy a fijar yo, pero el desarrollo del pasado dónde el usuario podía seleccionar entre varias opciones).

¿Cómo se puede maquetar el dashboard con las distintas respuestas devueltas por llamadas realizadas por cURL?

¿Debo realizar la maquetación para cada PHP que llamo con cURL o únicamente podría hacerlo en el PHP Dashboard que llamará a los distintos PHP con cURL?

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad. Siento decirte que tal y como redactas la pregunta no entiendo qué es lo que deseas hacer. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo algo más claro o algún esquema que facilite la comprensión? Por ejemplo, las peticiones cURL imagino que las hace el PHP, ¿a quién le envía esas peticiones? ¿para qué las necesita? ¿Qué obtiene?

Comment: Quiero tener 1 php a modo de dashboard o panel. La información con la que alimento este PHP viene de otros PHPs que utilizan cURL para hacer consultas concretas. Deseo maquetar correctamente mi Dashboard.

Comment: Pero, ¿Los PHP que quieres llamar con curl son externos o están junto al otro? En ese caso deberías pensar en [`require`](https://php.net/require).

Comment: Todos los PHP son desarrollos propios y en servidor propio. Utilizo cURL para poder enviar unas variables determinadas mediante el método post.

Comment: Pero, si estás ejecutando el código PHP en el lado del servidor, ¿para qué necesitas realizar una nueva petición servidor-servidor para enviar el valor de variables? ¿No has pensado que con `require` puedes compartir las variables que necesites? Si explicas mejor qué variables debes compartir o qué deseas hacer quizá te pueda proponer una forma mejor y más sencilla de llevar a cabo el trabajo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Parto de distintos PHP que contienen forms de HTML. Son pequeñas piezas que forman la información que quiero mostrar en 1 única página PHP (Dashboard) En este caso, En el dashboard pasaría yo unos valores concretos, sin que el usuario pudiera elegir. Por eso, proponía utilizar cURL para pasar por POST unos valores fijos.